# $V(\mathfrak{a} \cap \mathfrak{b}) = V(\mathfrak{a}) \cup V(\mathfrak{b})$ (Spectrum of a commutative ring)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $V(\mathfrak{a})$ be all ideals in ${\rm Spec}(A)$ that contain ideal $\mathfrak{a}$.  Then $V(\mathfrak{a} \cap \mathfrak{b}) = V(\mathfrak{a}) \cup V(\mathfrak{b})$.

$\mathfrak{p} \in$ RHS means $\mathfrak{p}$ contains one of the two so obviously contains the intersection.  OTOH, $\mathfrak{p} \in$ LHS, then $\mathfrak{p} \supset \mathfrak{a} \cap \mathfrak{b}$.  For all $a \in \mathfrak{a}$.  Let $a \in \mathfrak{a}, b \in \mathfrak{b}$, then $ab \in \mathfrak{a} \cap \mathfrak{b}$ since each absorbs the whole ring $A$.  Then we have that either $a$ or $b \in \mathfrak{p}$.  What now?

Comment: how do you make those special letter symbols that usually stand for ideals?

Comment: "\mathfrak a" or "\mathfrak{a}" makes $\mathfrak a$

Comment: $\mathfrak{a}$ \mathfrak

Comment: Did you mean $V(\mathfrak a \cup \mathfrak b) = V(\mathfrak a) \cap V(\mathfrak b)$ or $V(\mathfrak a \cap \mathfrak b) = V(\mathfrak a) \cup V(\mathfrak b)$?  The way you've written it is not true.

Comment: @Guest oops ur right

Comment: V(a∪b)=V(a)∩V(b) and V(ab)=V(a)∪V(b)

Comment: The first of those is trivial, it basically says that an ideal contains both $\mathfrak a$ and $\mathfrak b$ iff it contains $\mathfrak a \cup \mathfrak b$.

Comment: For the second you use a version of the prime avoidance lemma, it's 1.11 in Atiyah-MacDonald if you have access to it.

Comment: @Guest  Thanks.  I do have a copy of that book and will go over the theorem.

Comment: You really don't need the full power of prime avoidance. It's much much easier here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can show the following equalities
$$V(\mathfrak{a} \mathfrak{b}) = V(\mathfrak{a} \cap \mathfrak{b}) = V(\mathfrak{a}) \cup V(\mathfrak{b}).$$

Because $\mathfrak{a}\mathfrak{b} \subseteq \mathfrak{a}\cap \mathfrak{b}$, we have
$$V(\mathfrak{a}\cap \mathfrak{b}) \subseteq V(\mathfrak{a}\mathfrak{b})$$
because any prime that contains $\mathfrak{a} \cap \mathfrak{b}$ must also contain $\mathfrak{a}\mathfrak{b}$.

Then, we have $V(\mathfrak{a}) \cup V(\mathfrak{b}) \subseteq V(\mathfrak{a} \cap \mathfrak{b}$ by what you've already shown. So, we're left with one containment to show, $V(\mathfrak{ab}) \subseteq V(\mathfrak{a}) \cup V(\mathfrak{b}).$

To show this, suppose a prime $\mathfrak{p}$ contains $\mathfrak{a}\mathfrak{b}$ and suppose for contradiction that it contains neither $\mathfrak{a}$ or $\mathfrak{b}$. Then, there must be elements $a \in \mathfrak{a} \backslash \mathfrak{p}, b \in \mathfrak{b} \backslash \mathfrak{p}.$ Because $\mathfrak{p}$ is prime, this implies that $ab \in \mathfrak{a}\mathfrak{b} \backslash \mathfrak{p}$ (as $ab \in \mathfrak{p} \Rightarrow a \in \mathfrak{p} \text{ or }b \in \mathfrak{p}.$)

But this is a contradiction because $\mathfrak{p}$ contains $\mathfrak{a}\mathfrak{b}$. Hence, $\mathfrak{p}$ must contain one of $\mathfrak{a}, \mathfrak{b}$, finishing the proof.